# PHP read last few lines of the file without copying the entire file to memory

Tags: php

Well you know I can use this:

```
<?php
$myfile = 'myfile.txt';
$command = "tac $myfile > /tmp/myfilereversed.txt";
exec($command);
$currentRow = 0;
$numRows = 20;  // stops after this number of rows
$handle = fopen("/tmp/myfilereversed.txt", "r");
while (!feof($handle) && $currentRow <= $numRows) {
   $currentRow++;
   $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
   echo $buffer."<br>";
}
fclose($handle);
?>
```

But doesn't it copy the whole file to memory?

A better approach maybe `fread()` but it uses the bytes so might also not be the a good approach too.

My file can go into around 100MB so I want it.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510141/php-read-last-line-from-file/1510248#1510248

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510141/php-read-last-line-from-file/1510248#1510248

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15025877/995958

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read only 5 last line of the text file in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961618/how-to-read-only-5-last-line-of-the-text-file-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're already doing stuff on the command line, why not use `tail` directly:

```
$myfile = 'myfile.txt';
$command = "tail -20 $myfile";
$lines = explode("\n", shell_exec($command));
```

Not tested, but should work without PHP having to read the whole file.

Comment: A bit of explanation please :D

Comment: man `tail` from terminal/bash ;). Source php manual for `shell_exec`.

Comment: The best way to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

Try applying this logic as it might help: [read long file in reverse order fgets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php#62774)

Comment: Dude read my question carefully i alreaded put that comment -.-

Answer (score 0):

Most `f*()`-functions are stream-based and therefore will only read into memory, what should get read.

As fas as I understand you want to read the last `$numRows` line from a file. A maybe naive solution

```
$result = array();
while (!feof($handle)) {
  array_push($result, fgets($handle, 4096));
  if (count($result) > $numRows) array_shift($result);
}
```

If you know (lets say) the maximum line length, you can try to guess a position, that is nearer at the end of the file, but before at least `$numRows` the end

```
$seek = $maxLineLength * ($numRows + 5); // +5 to assure, we are not too far
fseek($handle, -$seek, SEEK_END);
// See code above
```