# What is the best way to read last lines (i.e. "tail") from a file using PHP?

Tags: php, performance, logging

In my PHP application I need to **read multiple lines starting from the end of 
many files** (mostly logs). Sometimes I need only the last one, sometimes I need 
tens or hundreds. Basically, I want something as flexible as the Unix `tail`
command.

There are questions here about how to get the single last line from a file (but
I need *N* lines), and different solutions were given. I'm not sure about which 
one is the best and which performs better.

Comment: `$file = file('filename.txt');
echo $file[count($file) - 1];`

Comment: @Winston Basically that's solution #1 in my answer. Check it out, for big files it's absolutely to avoid!

Comment: PHP Tail library makes this quite easy: https://packagist.org/packages/icyapril/tail

Answer (score 297, accepted):

### Methods overview

Searching on the internet, I came across different solutions. I can group them
in three approaches:

- *naive* ones that use `file()` PHP function;
- *cheating* ones that runs `tail` command on the system;
- *mighty* ones that happily jump around an opened file using `fseek()`.

I ended up choosing (or writing) five solutions, a *naive* one, a *cheating* one 
and three *mighty* ones.

1. The most concise [***naive* solution**](https://gist.github.com/d9a609b513d881bdad47), 
   using built-in array functions.
2. The [**only possible solution based on `tail`** command](https://gist.github.com/5cbf78a4447e1a98b59f), which has
   a little big problem: it does not run if `tail` is not available, i.e. on
   non-Unix (Windows) or on restricted environments that don't allow system
   functions.
3. The solution in which **single bytes** are read from the end of file searching 
   for (and counting) new-line characters, found **[here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php#69008)**.
4. The **multi-byte buffered** solution optimized for large files, found 
   **[here](http://www.geekality.net/2011/05/28/php-tail-tackling-large-files/)**.
5. A slightly [**modified version of solution #4**](https://gist.github.com/1711e81a9162320fde20) in which buffer length is 
   dynamic, decided according to the number of lines to retrieve.

All solutions **work**. In the sense that they return the expected result from
any file and for any number of lines we ask for (except for solution #1, that can
break PHP memory limits in case of large files, returning nothing). But which one 
is better?

### Performance tests

To answer the question I run tests. That's how these thing are done, isn't it?

I prepared a sample **100 KB file** joining together different files found in
my `/var/log` directory. Then I wrote a PHP script that uses each one of the 
five solutions to retrieve *1, 2, .., 10, 20, ... 100, 200, ..., 1000* lines 
from the end of the file. Each single test is repeated ten times (that's 
something like *5 × 28 × 10 = 1400* tests), measuring **average elapsed 
time** in microseconds.

I run the script on my local development machine (Xubuntu 12.04,
PHP 5.3.10, 2.70 GHz dual core CPU, 2 GB RAM) using the PHP command line 
interpreter. Here are the results:

[image: Execution time on sample 100 KB log file]

Solution #1 and #2 seem to be the worse ones. Solution #3 is good only when we need to
read a few lines. **Solutions #4 and #5 seem to be the best ones.**
Note how dynamic buffer size can optimize the algorithm: execution time is a little
smaller for few lines, because of the reduced buffer.

Let's try with a bigger file. What if we have to read a **10 MB** log file?

[image: Execution time on sample 10 MB log file]

Now solution #1 is by far the worse one: in fact, loading the whole 10 MB file 
into memory is not a great idea. I run the tests also on 1MB and 100MB file, 
and it's practically the same situation.

And for tiny log files? That's the graph for a **10 KB** file:

[image: Execution time on sample 10 KB log file]

Solution #1 is the best one now! Loading a 10 KB into memory isn't a big deal
for PHP. Also #4 and #5 performs good. However this is an edge case: a 10 KB log
means something like 150/200 lines...

> *You can download all my test files, sources and results 
>   [here](http://www.lorenzostanco.com/stack/test_tail.zip).*

### Final thoughts

**[Solution #5](https://gist.github.com/1711e81a9162320fde20)** is heavily recommended for the general use case: works great
with every file size and performs particularly good when reading a few lines.

Avoid **[solution #1](https://gist.github.com/d9a609b513d881bdad47)** if you 
should read files bigger than 10 KB.

Solution **[#2](https://gist.github.com/5cbf78a4447e1a98b59f)** 
and **[#3](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php#69008)** 
aren't the best ones for each test I run: #2 never runs in less than 
2ms, and #3 is heavily influenced by the number of
lines you ask (works quite good only with 1 or 2 lines).

Comment: Btw, how about putting the code on BitBucket or something instead of in an annoying zip file? :p

Comment: Also... not quite sure your optimization is really that necessary, hehe. Not that much difference.

Comment: @Svish The code is on a GitHub Gist. If you are talking about the whole test files, I think it's unnecessary to put them in a repo... About the optimization: I really wanted to focus on performances because I had to use that code very intensely for few lines reading (less than 10). So, a large buffer seemed unnecessary to me. Note that axis are logarithmic: for few lines a reduced buffer means half the execution time!

Comment: It clumps all lines into one. Can we retain line breaks?

Comment: Aye, need to retain line breaks as the file I'm pulling from is a log. Each line is a separate event. Any way to modify the code to preserve the line breaks?

Comment: @Jguy to me, line breaks are retained in all the five script version. How are you using the code?

Comment: I am using Solution 5 in a model in CodeIgniter. `return trim($output);` gets returned to the controller via `$data['log'] = $this->mymodel->return_log();` which then gets passed to the view and just simply echo'ed

Comment: @Jguy Don't know much about CodeIgniter, but maybe you echo it without replacing `"\n"`s with `<br/>`s? Try wrapping it in [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php). If it works, consider using [`htmlentities()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) too.

Comment: Yeah, removing the trim and using `echo nl2br($log);` works just fine and <br /> are preserved. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it's a one off but the links aren't working. I'm getting SSL error on both firefox and chrome.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what the answer would be for a 1GB file with ~ 1M lines, it looks like #2 and #4/5 are approaching each other.

Comment: @Yehosef Ok, maybe you can have a 1GB file, but It's quite unusual you need to read a million lines from the end of it :)

Comment: ah.. I think I misunderstood what's the number of lines - I thought it was the number of lines of the file - from your comment I gather it means the number of lines from the end.    The exact use case I'm working with is that  we're downloading log files from a provider that are sometimes truncated due to a problem on their end.  To verify the integrity I want to check the last 3 characters. We're currently doing that with system call to "tail -c3"  But I came here b/c I was curious if I could efficiently do the same in php without a system call.

Comment: possibly one of the best SO answers I have ever seen. Options, multiple tests, conclusions. You need a medal.

Comment: @David incidentally, this post is a complete off topic, as it doesn't contain any *answer*. In order to get your answer, you have to go to another site, which is directly prohibited by the rules.

Comment: I get this error when using the function from Solution #5 "crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated."

Answer (score 5):

This is a modified version which can also skip last lines:

```
/**
 * Modified version of http://www.geekality.net/2011/05/28/php-tail-tackling-large-files/ and of https://gist.github.com/lorenzos/1711e81a9162320fde20
 * @author Kinga the Witch (Trans-dating.com), Torleif Berger, Lorenzo Stanco
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/15025877/995958
 * @license http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
 */    
function tailWithSkip($filepath, $lines = 1, $skip = 0, $adaptive = true)
{
  // Open file
  $f = @fopen($filepath, "rb");
  if (@flock($f, LOCK_SH) === false) return false;
  if ($f === false) return false;

  if (!$adaptive) $buffer = 4096;
  else {
    // Sets buffer size, according to the number of lines to retrieve.
    // This gives a performance boost when reading a few lines from the file.
    $max=max($lines, $skip);
    $buffer = ($max < 2 ? 64 : ($max < 10 ? 512 : 4096));
  }

  // Jump to last character
  fseek($f, -1, SEEK_END);

  // Read it and adjust line number if necessary
  // (Otherwise the result would be wrong if file doesn't end with a blank line)
  if (fread($f, 1) == "\n") {
    if ($skip > 0) { $skip++; $lines--; }
  } else {
    $lines--;
  }

  // Start reading
  $output = '';
  $chunk = '';
  // While we would like more
  while (ftell($f) > 0 && $lines >= 0) {
    // Figure out how far back we should jump
    $seek = min(ftell($f), $buffer);

    // Do the jump (backwards, relative to where we are)
    fseek($f, -$seek, SEEK_CUR);

    // Read a chunk
    $chunk = fread($f, $seek);

    // Calculate chunk parameters
    $count = substr_count($chunk, "\n");
    $strlen = mb_strlen($chunk, '8bit');

    // Move the file pointer
    fseek($f, -$strlen, SEEK_CUR);

    if ($skip > 0) { // There are some lines to skip
      if ($skip > $count) { $skip -= $count; $chunk=''; } // Chunk contains less new line symbols than
      else {
        $pos = 0;

        while ($skip > 0) {
          if ($pos > 0) $offset = $pos - $strlen - 1; // Calculate the offset - NEGATIVE position of last new line symbol
          else $offset=0; // First search (without offset)

          $pos = strrpos($chunk, "\n", $offset); // Search for last (including offset) new line symbol

          if ($pos !== false) $skip--; // Found new line symbol - skip the line
          else break; // "else break;" - Protection against infinite loop (just in case)
        }
        $chunk=substr($chunk, 0, $pos); // Truncated chunk
        $count=substr_count($chunk, "\n"); // Count new line symbols in truncated chunk
      }
    }

    if (strlen($chunk) > 0) {
      // Add chunk to the output
      $output = $chunk . $output;
      // Decrease our line counter
      $lines -= $count;
    }
  }

  // While we have too many lines
  // (Because of buffer size we might have read too many)
  while ($lines++ < 0) {
    // Find first newline and remove all text before that
    $output = substr($output, strpos($output, "\n") + 1);
  }

  // Close file and return
  @flock($f, LOCK_UN);
  fclose($f);
  return trim($output);
}
```

Comment: Are you *positively* sure that locking a constantly updated file you are going to *watch* is ever a good idea?

Answer (score 3):

This would also work:

```
$file = new SplFileObject("/path/to/file");
$file->seek(PHP_INT_MAX); // cheap trick to seek to EoF
$total_lines = $file->key(); // last line number

// output the last twenty lines
$reader = new LimitIterator($file, $total_lines - 20);
foreach ($reader as $line) {
    echo $line; // includes newlines
}
```

Or without the `LimitIterator`:

```
$file = new SplFileObject($filepath);
$file->seek(PHP_INT_MAX);
$total_lines = $file->key();
$file->seek($total_lines - 20);
while (!$file->eof()) {
    echo $file->current();
    $file->next();
}
```

Unfortunately, your testcase segfaults on my machine, so I cannot tell how it performs.

Comment: I didn't know about the `SplFileObject` class, thank you. Don't know why the test sigfaults on your machine, anyway I run it alongside the better method (#5) for the 10MB file, and the performance is not quite good, it's comparable to the shell method (#2). See **[here](http://i.imgur.com/cWdYrzE.png)**.

Comment: Note that first solution with `LimitIterator` will throw `OutOfRangeException` if you have less that 20 lines in your file, stating `Parameter offset must be >= 0`.
The second one will throw `LogicException` for, basically, same reason.

Comment: Most people finding this solution good do not realize that there is no way to implement cheap seek() function, which makes this code inevitably read **every single line** from the file, making it O(n) solution as opposed to O(1) for the fseek-based solutions. Therefore it shouldn't be recommended for the large files.

Answer (score 3):

My little copy paste solution after reading all this here.

```
/**
 * @param $pathname
 * @param $lines
 * @param bool $echo
 * @return int
 */
private function tailonce($pathname, $lines, $echo = true)
{
    $realpath = realpath($pathname);
    $fp = fopen($realpath, 'r', FALSE);
    $flines = 0;
    $a = -1;
    while ($flines <= $lines) {
        fseek($fp, $a--, SEEK_END);
        $char = fread($fp, 1);
        if ($char == "\n") $flines++;
    }
    $out = fread($fp, 1000000);
    fclose($fp);
    if ($echo) echo $out;
    return $a+2;
}
```

A continuous tail function as in `tail -f`
It does not close $fp cause you must kill it with
Ctrl-C anyway. usleep for saving your cpu time, only tested on windows so far.

```
/**
 * @param $pathname
 */
private function tail($pathname)
{
    $realpath = realpath($pathname);
    $fp = fopen($realpath, 'r', FALSE);
    $lastline = '';
    fseek($fp, $this->tailonce($pathname, 1, false), SEEK_END);
    do {
        $line = fread($fp, 1000);
        if ($line == $lastline) {
            usleep(50);
        } else {
            $lastline = $line;
            echo $lastline;
        }
    } while ($fp);
}
```

You need to put this code into a class!

Comment: Very good ideas in general but many annoying little flaws. Such as reading by one char, assuming that 1000000 will be enough, useless $echo variable

Answer (score 0):

Yet another function, you can use regexes to separate items. Usage

```
$last_rows_array = file_get_tail('logfile.log', 100, array(
  'regex'     => true,          // use regex
  'separator' => '#\n{2,}#',   //  separator: at least two newlines
  'typical_item_size' => 200, //   line length
));
```

The function:

```
// public domain
function file_get_tail( $file, $requested_num = 100, $args = array() ){
  // default arg values
  $regex         = true;
  $separator     = null;
  $typical_item_size = 100; // estimated size
  $more_size_mul = 1.01; // +1%
  $max_more_size = 4000;
  extract( $args );
  if( $separator === null )  $separator = $regex ? '#\n+#' : "\n";

  if( is_string( $file ))  $f = fopen( $file, 'rb');
  else if( is_resource( $file ) && in_array( get_resource_type( $file ), array('file', 'stream'), true ))
    $f = $file;
  else throw new \Exception( __METHOD__.': file must be either filename or a file or stream resource');

  // get file size
  fseek( $f, 0, SEEK_END );
  $fsize = ftell( $f );
  $fpos = $fsize;
  $bytes_read = 0;

  $all_items = array(); // array of array
  $all_item_num = 0;
  $remaining_num = $requested_num;
  $last_junk = '';

  while( true ){
    // calc size and position of next chunk to read
    $size = $remaining_num * $typical_item_size - strlen( $last_junk );
    // reading a bit more can't hurt
    $size += (int)min( $size * $more_size_mul, $max_more_size );
    if( $size < 1 )  $size = 1;

    // set and fix read position
    $fpos = $fpos - $size;
    if( $fpos < 0 ){
      $size -= -$fpos;
      $fpos = 0;
    }

    // read chunk + add junk from prev iteration
    fseek( $f, $fpos, SEEK_SET );
    $chunk = fread( $f, $size );
    if( strlen( $chunk ) !== $size )  throw new \Exception( __METHOD__.": read error?");
    $bytes_read += strlen( $chunk );
    $chunk .= $last_junk;

    // chunk -> items, with at least one element
    $items = $regex ? preg_split( $separator, $chunk ) : explode( $separator, $chunk );

    // first item is probably cut in half, use it in next iteration ("junk") instead
    // also skip very first '' item
    if( $fpos > 0 || $items[0] === ''){
      $last_junk = $items[0];
      unset( $items[0] );
    } // … else noop, because this is the last iteration

    // ignore last empty item. end( empty [] ) === false
    if( end( $items ) === '')  array_pop( $items );

    // if we got items, push them
    $num = count( $items );
    if( $num > 0 ){
      $remaining_num -= $num;
      // if we read too much, use only needed items
      if( $remaining_num < 0 )  $items = array_slice( $items, - $remaining_num );
      // don't fix $remaining_num, we will exit anyway

      $all_items[] = array_reverse( $items );
      $all_item_num += $num;
    }

    // are we ready?
    if( $fpos === 0 || $remaining_num <= 0 )  break;

    // calculate a better estimate
    if( $all_item_num > 0 )  $typical_item_size = (int)max( 1, round( $bytes_read / $all_item_num ));
  }

  fclose( $f ); 

  //tr( $all_items );
  return call_user_func_array('array_merge', $all_items );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the following method, but it won't work on files up to 2GB.

```
<?php
    function lastLines($file, $lines) {
        $size = filesize($file);
        $fd=fopen($file, 'r+');
        $pos = $size;
        $n=0;
        while ( $n < $lines+1 && $pos > 0) {
            fseek($fd, $pos);
            $a = fread($fd, 1);
            if ($a === "\n") {
                ++$n;
            };
            $pos--;
        }
        $ret = array();
        for ($i=0; $i<$lines; $i++) {
            array_push($ret, fgets($fd));
        }
        return $ret;
    }
    print_r(lastLines('hola.php', 4));
?>
```