# PHP script to check recent errors in Apache

Tags: php, apache, sh

I want to monitor apache for recent "500 server error". If found send an email to somebody.

I don't know how to search the apache errors.log file for the latest errors.

Script could be PHP or SH. Whichever fits best.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: why you want to do this ? (if a script start attack you site your server ip will be spam ...)

Comment: I want to know if site is throwing a 500 error on any page/sevice to address the problem ASAP and don't wait for a customer to tell me "checkout is not working"

Comment: Automated testing.:  Selenium + Browserstack ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially want to "tail" the error file.
See [What is the best way in PHP to read last lines from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025875/what-is-the-best-way-in-php-to-read-last-lines-from-a-file)
You also need to consider that you need to keep track of what errors have already been sent so you don't keep sending the same error.  And as @Roboticsexpert mentions... you need a way to throttle the errors.    you don't want to generate a gazillion errors if there's an error under heavy server load.

Perhaps a more elegant solution is an error handler that does the notifying?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php