# How to view live overwritten file in terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have an output file which is constantly overwritten. There is a command in terminal tail -f filename which is helpful when the results are appended in the output file. However, I want to observe the first 10 or 20 lines of the constantly overwritten output file. Is there any such command?

Comment: do you want a refresh every given period  or only if the file has changed

Comment: Do you want or need any guarantee that you will read the file at least once between each write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refreshes every 1 second and prints first 100 lines of filename

```
watch -n 1 head -100 filename
```

Answer (score 0):

If using [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/) you would use [wait_on](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=wait_on), for example:

```
#!/bin/sh

while :; do
    tail file
    wait_on -w file
done
```

You may need to install it by using `pkg install wait_on`

In Linux you could use `inotifywait` something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

inotifywait --quiet --monitor --event modify file | while read; do
   tail file;
done
```

Based on your distro you may need to install the `inotify-tools` package, for example in [CentOS](https://www.centos.org/): `yum install inotify-tools`

For more options check the answer to this quesion: https://superuser.com/q/181517/284722

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion using **php**.

In the command line. This won't load the whole file in memory.

Output first 8192bytes of *seed.txt*.

```
php -r "echo fread(fopen('seed.txt','r'), 8192);"
```

> fread() reads up to length bytes from the file pointer referenced by
>   handle. Reading stops as soon as one of the following conditions is
>   met http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15025877/2494754