# Allowed memory size exhausted error when reading file

Tags: php

Help me, please.

When I'm trying to read a file using

```
$tmp = file('file.log');
```

I get an error

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 90 bytes) in script.php on line 37
```

php memory limit is 128M, size of file.log is only 48M.

Comment: Do you really need to whole file at a time?

Comment: Gumbo, I need to read last N lines of a big file. How can I do it without reading all file?

Comment: No need to read the whole file into memory. The overhead might come from turning it into one large array. You should use fgets/fgetc and fseek for things like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510141/read-last-line-from-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that something have consumed some amount of memory before. You allocate 128M for all operations, data and so on in your script. And memory has finished in this place only because your script exceeded it trying to sum, for example,
 **87M(uses by something earlier)+48M(your file).**

Comment: memory limit is a limit for one php script?

Comment: For one process and yes in your case is for one script.