# php code to display the Latest reading from a Array

Tags: php

I have a code which will Display the log file data in the attached format,
Here it will display all the readings in the table 
I need to display only the Latest or Last Reading how to display that?Please help me.I have attached the Log file in the link
[Log File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nanne31awysgl5u/192.168.1.12_10000-gprs20160525.log?dl=0)

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" > 
 <html>
 <h1><center>Online Real Time Temperature and Pressure Monitoring System</center></h1>
 <head>
 <style>
 table,th,td{
border:1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td{
padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table align ="center" style="width:60%">
<tr>
<th>Year</th>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Sensor ID</th>
<th>Position</th>
<th>Pressure(psi)</th>
<th>Temperature</th>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
<?PHP
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
$file_handle = fopen("D:/192.168.1.12_10000-gprs20160525.log", "rb");
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
$line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
$parts = explode(' ', $line_of_text);
$finalstr=$parts[0]."<BR>";
$hello=explode('>',end($parts));
$hello2=$hello[0]."<BR>";
$hello3=strlen($hello2);
if($hello3==23){
$timestamp=$hello2;
}
elseif($hello3==27)
{
$data=$hello2;
$hello4=explode('-',$timestamp."-".$data);
$year = substr($hello4[0],1,4);
$Month = substr($hello4[0],5,2);
$Date = substr($hello4[0],7,2);
$Hour = substr($hello4[0],9,2);
$Min = substr($hello4[0],11,2);
$sec =  substr($hello4[0],13,2);
$time= $Hour.":".$Min.":".$sec;
$sensorid1=substr($hello4[1],4,2);
$sensorid2=substr($hello4[1],7,2);
$Pressure1=substr($hello4[1],10,2);
$Pressure2=substr($hello4[1],13,2);
$temperature=substr($hello4[1],16,2);
$finalsensor=$sensorid1.$sensorid2;
$finalPressure=$Pressure1.$Pressure2;
$finalPressure1=(hexdec($finalPressure)-1531)/100+0.61;
$finaltemperature1=hexdec($temperature)-40;
$position="FL";

 ?>
 <html>
 <head>

 </head>
 <body>

  <tr>
  <td><center><?php echo ($year);?></center></td>
  <td><center><?php echo ($Month); ?></center></td>
  <td><center><?php echo ($Date); ?></center></td>
  <td><center><?php echo ($time); ?></center></td>
  <td><center><?php echo ($finalsensor); ?></center></td>
  <td><center><?php echo ($position); ?></center></td>
  <td><center><?php echo ($finalPressure1); ?></center></td>
  <td><center><?php echo ($finaltemperature1); ?></center></td>


  </tr>
  </body>
 </html>
  <?php
  }
  elseif($hello3==50)
  {
   echo "";
   }
   }
  fclose($file_handle);

   ?>
```

Comment: your link shows a 404, but presuming each line contains a new record, this may be what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510141/read-last-line-from-file

Comment: Link shows 404 error but on the top left corner you can find the download option which will download the file,

Comment: I've seen the link you have posted ,but The data logging in the file has lot of unwanted data which i will filter in the code and i need Filtered data only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way in PHP to read last lines from a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025875/what-is-the-best-way-in-php-to-read-last-lines-from-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code re-assigns `$data` everytime 27 characters are detected, if you  want to print just the last set of result, simply move the string decomposition (all the `substr()`) and echoing part outside the `while` loop.

There is no need to close and reopen the `<html>` and `<body>` tags between parts.

If the latest value is all you need, you should consider rewriting your code. Read the log bottom to top, as soon as a line containing 27 characters is detected, find the next line that contains 23 characters, then return `$hello4` at first instance of assignment to break loop, way more efficient and memory friendly.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" > 
 <html>
 <h1><center>Online Real Time Temperature and Pressure Monitoring System</center></h1>
 <head>
 <style>
table,th,td{
border:1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td{
padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table align ="center" style="width:60%">
<tr>
<th>Year</th>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Sensor ID</th>
<th>Position</th>
<th>Pressure(psi)</th>
<th>Temperature</th>
</tr>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
$file_handle = fopen("temp.log", "rb");
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts = explode(' ', $line_of_text);
    $finalstr=$parts[0]."<BR>";
    $hello=explode('>',end($parts));
    $hello2=$hello[0]."<BR>";
    $hello3=strlen($hello2);
    if($hello3==23){
        $timestamp=$hello2;
    }
    elseif($hello3==27)
    {
        $data=$hello2;
        $hello4=explode('-',$timestamp."-".$data);
    }
    elseif ($hello3 == 50)
    {
        echo "";
    }
}
fclose($file_handle);
$year = substr($hello4[0], 1, 4);
$Month = substr($hello4[0], 5, 2);
$Date = substr($hello4[0], 7, 2);
$Hour = substr($hello4[0], 9, 2);
$Min = substr($hello4[0], 11, 2);
$sec = substr($hello4[0], 13, 2);
$time = $Hour . ":" . $Min . ":" . $sec;
$sensorid1 = substr($hello4[1], 4, 2);
$sensorid2 = substr($hello4[1], 7, 2);
$Pressure1 = substr($hello4[1], 10, 2);
$Pressure2 = substr($hello4[1], 13, 2);
$temperature = substr($hello4[1], 16, 2);
$finalsensor = $sensorid1 . $sensorid2;
$finalPressure = $Pressure1 . $Pressure2;
$finalPressure1 = (hexdec($finalPressure) - 1531) / 100 + 0.61;
$finaltemperature1 = hexdec($temperature) - 40;
$position = "FL";
?>
  <tr>
  <td><center><?php
echo ($year); ?></center></td>
  <td><center><?php
echo ($Month); ?></center></td>
  <td><center><?php
echo ($Date); ?></center></td>
  <td><center><?php
echo ($time); ?></center></td>
  <td><center><?php
echo ($finalsensor); ?></center></td>
  <td><center><?php
echo ($position); ?></center></td>
  <td><center><?php
echo ($finalPressure1); ?></center></td>
  <td><center><?php
echo ($finaltemperature1); ?></center></td>
  </tr>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Glad to be of help but please learn to use trim() and strpos(), you are creating unnecessary processes and arrays for nothing. You don't need to use a single explode() for this.

Answer (score 0):

Display only the last line in that file.

Calculate total lines in that file,
Iterate each line and skip the line if it is not the last line.

Comment: Each line Display as separate array So each line showing count of 1 line