# CSS Div To Display Server Logs

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to display server side logs on browser but problems is I can not display whole log text inside a div therefore I need a div that only display last 100 or 200 lines and hide the previous logs text and only display the newly added text.

I googled allot but did not find anything.

Thank You.

**UPDATE**
I got the solution

```
var length = $("#parentDiv > #childDiv").length;

if(length > 20){    //20 is no of lines
     $('#parentDiv').find('#childDiv:lt(4)').remove();   //remove first four div
}
```

Comment: When you say some number of lines, it's certainly not countable. Do you have line separator such as <br> tag? Show some sample of your work if you have tried out.

Comment: I used div for each line

Comment: A simple approach would be running a loop through the divs using JS and take the last 100 or 200 divs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it following steps:

**Step 1.** Make Parent div to hold all inner divs those have lines:

```
<div  id="logHolder"> </div>
```

**Step 2.**  Add all child divs that have log lines in that div like below:

```
$( "#logHolder" ).appendHTML("<div> Log Line 1 </div><div> Log Line 2 </div>") // and so on..
```

**Step 3.** Use jquery slice function to select few children divs like below:

```
$("#logHolder > div").slice(-100);
```

**Note :** You need to refresh slice function as soon as you append more lines to logholder div.

I will discourage using css for this requirement as it gives poor Cross Browser Compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is not so much how to display log, but rather how to display *the most recent lines of the log* (the last lines of the file). Especially in an efficient manner.

With unix, you would use `tail` to read lines from the end of a file. With PHP, there isn't a convenient function (to my knowledge) but it is possible using fseek.

This answer explains how to read from the end of a file backwards:

[PHP - Returning the last line in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062716/php-returning-the-last-line-in-a-file#answer-1062737)

The answer above the one I just linked is a simpler solution, but it loads the entire file into memory (and then displays the last lines). The fseek solution should be cleaner, and have better performance.

I haven't personally used this method, however.