# Display the last 100 lines of a log file in real time

Tags: php, html, file, logging

I want to be able to display the last 100 lines of a log file in a div window, and have it update in real time, so if something would be written to the log, the window would write the new log content for the user to see. Currently I'm doing this only once but it works fine, I just need a way to update it real time every second:

```
<?php
$file = "logfile.log";
$f = fopen($file, "r");
while ($line = fgets($f, 100) ) {
    print $line . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You'll have to use a timer + ajax via javascript to call a PHP script to get the latest lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Returning the last line in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062716/php-returning-the-last-line-in-a-file)

Comment: @cmorrissey OP states: *"Currently I'm doing this only once but it works fine, I just need a way to update it real time every second"*.

Comment: You could add a header to auto-refresh the page at a certain interval.  Simpler than ajax. 
  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp

Comment: @Nic that would refresh the whole page, not just the div.

Comment: @aynber: yep, sorry my mistake.

Comment: Also, your code reads the entire file from top to bottom in 99 Bytes incremets

Comment: @Fred-ii- it defiantly doesn't work the way he has described it, its reading the entire file.  Which is why I posted to close it as a duplicate as that has the correct answer on it

Comment: @cmorrissey alrighty ;-) if you're 100% sure of the dupe, let me know and I'll hammer it. Just say the word.

Comment: @Fred-ii- posted a complete example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic solution.

Here is your html and js `index.php`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Read Log File</title>

</head>

<body>
<div>
    <ul id="log">

    </ul>
</div>
<script src="./jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 
<script>

    $(function(){

        setInterval(function(){
            $.getJSON( "./getLog.php", function( data ) {
              var $log = $('#log');
              $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                $log.prepend( "<li>" + val + "</li>" );
              });
            });

        },5000);

    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is your php file `getLog.php`

```
  <?php

  session_start();

  $file  = '/path/to/your/file_log';

  $total_lines = shell_exec('cat ' . escapeshellarg($file) . ' | wc -l');

  if(isset($_SESSION['current_line']) && $_SESSION['current_line'] < $total_lines){

    $lines = shell_exec('tail -n' . ($total_lines - $_SESSION['current_line']) . ' ' . escapeshellarg($file));

  } else if(!isset($_SESSION['current_line'])){

    $lines = shell_exec('tail -n100 ' . escapeshellarg($file));

  }

  $_SESSION['current_line'] = $total_lines;

  $lines_array = array_filter(preg_split('#[\r\n]+#', trim($lines)));

  if(count($lines_array)){
    echo json_encode($lines_array);
  }

  ?>
```